# Wine and PlayOnLinux open game in wrong resolution

Tags: wine, games, intel-graphics, display-resolution, playonlinux

I have a game - Delta Force Black Hawk Down - which I used to play on Windows but since I got rid of it (Windows) I tried to use `wine` to play. When I insert the CD to install I run the `autorun` and when I open the shortcut on the desktop the game is opens with a weird resolution.

When I somehow manage to open a new window, game's resolution seems fine. The problem started when I installed the games' extension pack from the OFFICIAL CD and then the game didn't open...

I removed `wine`, completely installed the latest one and installed the game again through `PlayOnLinux`. Sometimes the game freezes with weird sounds coming from it. However, in `PlayOnLinux` I'm not able to open a new window of the game.

So, this leads me to asking here how can I make my game open with the correct resolution automatically? The game supports several resolutions - none works - the one it configured according to my PC was 1024x768. I have Intel HD 3000 graphics.

[image]

Comment: This results https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=5277 aren't encouraging but also old. Newer reports are about the GOG version only https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=35070 are very good (Platinum), current and relevant. The version sold by GOG may differ from the original.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out the answer:

- Pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> changes the resolution for the desired (native) resolution for this game.

Running the game again confirmed the proper resolution is kept.